# Nginx return other code

Tags: nginx

I'm allowing a couple of IP's to access the page simply with `allow x.x.x.x` and then underneath it currently I'm using `deny all` and that works fine. However, it currently displays 403 as it should but can I change it to display another code of my choice? (for example, 404 for people who aren't in the allow list) 
I've also tested with `return 404` for example however it seems to not listen to the allows set and just returns it for every request.

Comment: Definitely don't want to do that lol - I'll just wait to see if anyone else has some advise / guidance.

Comment: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page

Answer (score 0):

[Docs for `error_page`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page) say:

> Furthermore, it is possible to change the response code to another using the “=response” syntax, for example:

```
error_page 404 =200 /empty.gif;
```

So in your case, that is:

```
error_page 403 =404 /404.html
```

So the sort of downside is having to create/copy the `404.html`.

You may, however, want to add an internal location:

```
location = /404.html {
    internal;
    return 404;
}
```

With that, you should be getting default NGINX 404 output, without having to tinker with copying/creating any extra error HTML files.

Comment: if you use internal directive, it' better to make "named location" /404.html

`error_page 403 =404 @404.html;`

`location @404.html {
    internal;
    allow all;
    return 404 'not found';
}`

and seems you forgot `allow all;` just in case ;)